# Display data from listBox into receipt using messagebox(or any other methods) in c#

Tags: c#, listbox

Hey guys this is my code for getting items from users and to calculate the total payment using C#. My problem is how do i do the Receipt part? I'm stuck. I don't know whether to use messagebox or use datagrid in another form. But I don't know how to use that. C# newbie here. Saw some tutorial in youtube to get this.

Thanks

```
    private void getValues(string custOrder)
    {
        order.item = custOrder.Split('$')[0];   
        order.price = Convert.ToDouble(custOrder.Split('$')[1]);    
        finalBill += "Ordered Item: " + order.item + "\nPrice: " + order.price.ToString("C2") + "\n";   //C2 for 2 Decimal places
        updateBill();       
    }

    private void updateBill()
    {
        subtotal += order.price;
        total += order.price + (order.price * TAX);
        totalTaxes += order.price * TAX;

        listBox1.Items.Clear();     Only output latest bills
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(finalBill.Split('\n'));  
        listBox1.Items.Add("Subtotal: " + subtotal.ToString("C2"));
        listBox1.Items.Add("Tax: " + totalTaxes.ToString("C2"));
        listBox1.Items.Add("Total: " + total.ToString("C2"));
    }


    private void boxSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {
        {
            if (sender == meals)
                getValues(meals.SelectedItem.ToString());
            else if (sender == sideorders)
                getValues(sideorders.SelectedItem.ToString());
            else
                getValues(drinks.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }

    }



    private void ResetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        subtotal = 0;
        total = 0;
        totalTaxes = 0;
        finalBill = "FINAL BILL : \n";
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void print_receipt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }
```

Comment: What is receipt part ?

Comment: at the last part . i manage to get the total tax and total payment. but how can i get every orders that has been made my the user?
        private void print_receipt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("\tRESTAURANT\n\n " + "Subtotal: " + subtotal.ToString("C2") + "\nTax: " + totalTaxes.ToString("C2"));

        }

Comment: I personally think, showing any report in a message box, is a very weird idea. Instead you can generate the report/receipt in a grid and can show wherever suited best.

Comment: yeah I thought so too. But having a grid in another form is kind of hard (for me). I tried that. But i do not know how to get my data from form1 into form2( where the grid is at) .

Comment: oh yeah . and this is just an assignment from my lecturer. She wants us to just display the receipt. Do not need to print it out . hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

There are a heap of ways to do what you are after, but a simple way would be to use a `foreach` statement and build a string such as....

```
string result;
foreach (string s in listbox1.items)
 {
 result = result + s + Environment.NewLine;
 }

MessageBox.Show(result);
```

If you really want to show it in a `MessageBox`!

By the way it is much safer to use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `"\n"`